# Add custom field to Magento Admin (URL field)

Tags: php, sql, magento

I'm trying to add a custom field in the Magento backend, at the Configuration -> Web section. I want to add an additional URL text space (can be in any of the sections, URL options, for example, would work well). How can I do that? I have seen other people who tried it by making a custom module, but that was for the category section. I need it at the Web section though, have not had success yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean in CMS pages?

Comment: you want to add a field in system configuration??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this via the official Magento blog: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_add_a_custom_module_for_custom_admin_config_options

Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an custom field to the web section. The best approach is to create a custom module for this.

In your system.xml you need to add your section to the Web section.

More information on [this blog](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add attribute for product (can be text *string* named URL text) you can do it in catalog/attributes/manage attributes here you can create a new EAV attribute.

Next go to catalog/attributes/ manage groups/ and there you can drag/drop attribute to the correct group (will be shown in product admin page in the left list of groups)

In template you can call a attribute by call $_product->getAtributteName (if the attribute was named atributte_name) or `$_product->getAnotherAttributeName` (for attribute named another_attribute_name).

Always make sure if attribute is enabled for **catalog / or product view you are using** to make possible "`get`..." call from that view.

If you want it for using at URL, you can edit URL call by adding it to the end of URL as a GET parameter example:

http://www.somestore.com/?yourproductorcategoryurl&myparmforurl=`<?php echo $_product->getSomeAtributteName ?>`

if you using attribute type list (list of defined values, it always return an id of attribute value, not name) then you can use `$_product->getAttributeText('name_of_your_attribute')`